# Continuous version of the union-closed sets conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $F = \{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ be a set of continuous functions $f_i: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$,
$i = 1, \ldots, n$, such that $f_i \in F \land f_j \in F \implies \max(f_i,f_j) \in F$.

I would like to just formulate, of course not prove it, a "continuous" version of the [Union-closed sets conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture).

A starting point could be: for any $F$ as defined above there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_0) \ge \frac{n(\max_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0)-\min_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0))}{2}$$

Could we conjecture a stronger inequality involving all values $f_1(x_0),\ldots,f_n(x_0)$ in the RHS (so that to have a higher RHS) and not just the minimum and maximum?

Comment: (i) For your "starting point" to imply the conclusion of the union-closed sets conjecture, you need to add the condition  $\max_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0)>0$. (ii) How, in this context, an "inequality involving all values $f_1(x_0),\ldots,f_n(x_0)$" be stronger than your displayed inequality, with the right-hand involving only the extrema of the values $f_1(x_0),\ldots,f_n(x_0)$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis thank you, (i) I have added the requirement $f_i(x) \ge 0$, (ii) I am not sure what you mean, I have edited the question to point out that I was thinking of ways of modifying the RHS to make it bigger.

Comment: (i) The additional requirement $f_i(x)\ge0$ is redundant and does not help. (ii) How can using intermediate values of the $f_i(x_0)$'s help increase the right-hand side?

Comment: OK now I understood observation (i) and I have removed the redundant $f_i(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: Your conjecture implies a modified conjecture $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_0) \ge \frac{n(\max_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0)+\min_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0))}{2}$
where we add the min to the max instead of subtracting it. (Proof: Just subtract the min from each $f_i$).

Comment: Well I have seen now that the conjecture is actually false and needs to be rewritten completely. Take e.g. $n = 3, f_1(x) = 1, f_2(x) = 2/10, f_3(x) = 1/10$, $f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_3(x)= 13/10 < 27/20 = 3(f_1(x)-f_3(x))/2$.

Answer (score 2):

A conjecture that implies the conclusion of the union-closed sets conjecture and is stronger than your (corrected) "starting point" is as follows:

> For any $F$ as defined above there exists some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_0) \ge \frac n2\,\max_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0)>0.$$

(Here, the correction is adding the inequality $\max_{1 \le i \le n} f_i(x_0)>0$, without which we will be unable to deduce the conclusion of the union-closed sets conjecture.)

On the other hand, it is unclear how using intermediate values of the $f_i(x_0)$'s can help strengthen the conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this might fail, but I have found a possible formulation:

> For any $F$ as defined above there exists $x_0 \in[0,1]$ such that:
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_0) \ge {\frac{n}{2\binom{m}{2}} \sum_{k=2}^m (k-1)g_k(x_0)}$$
> where $n \ge m \ge 2$, $g_1(x_0) \lt g_2(x_0) \lt \ldots \lt g_m(x_0)$, and $\{g_1(x_0),\ldots,g_m(x_0)\}$ is the set corresponding to the multiset $\{f_1(x_0),\ldots,f_n(x_0)\}$.